# CRM 2011 PLUGIN - PostTaskSetState

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm creating a plugin to, when the user set the status of a task in the crm, verify all tasks that are associated with a incident. If, there's no tasks opened, the incident should be closed.

When I use a profile to debug the plugin it works fine, but otherwise nothing happens.

```
 IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
            IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
            EntityReference entity = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"];
            ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
            cols.AllColumns = true;
            Entity entityComplete = service.Retrieve("task", entity.Id, cols);

            if (((OptionSetValue)entityComplete.Attributes["statecode"]).Value == 0) //se o status for cancelado ou concluído
            {
                if (entityComplete.Attributes.Keys.Contains("regardingobjectid") && ((EntityReference)entityComplete.Attributes["regardingobjectid"]).LogicalName == "incident")
                {

                    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
                    query.EntityName = "task";
                    query.ColumnSet = cols;
                    query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("task", "incident", "regardingobjectid", "incidentid", JoinOperator.Inner));
                    query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0));
                    query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("activityid", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, entityComplete.Id));
                    query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("regardingobjectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, ((EntityReference)entityComplete.Attributes["regardingobjectid"]).Id));
                    EntityCollection collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                    if (collection.Entities.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Entity incident = service.Retrieve("incident", ((EntityReference)entityComplete.Attributes["regardingobjectid"]).Id, cols);
                        SetStateRequest setState = new SetStateRequest();
                        setState.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference();
                        setState.EntityMoniker.Id = incident.Id;
                        setState.EntityMoniker.LogicalName = incident.LogicalName;
                        setState.State = new OptionSetValue(1);
                        SetStateResponse setStateResponse = (SetStateResponse)service.Execute(setState);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Somebody can help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: So just attaching the debugger causes it to work correctly?

Comment: Are you getting any Errors in the Trace Log?  Maybe in order to debug if in the debugger, it is running as a different user?

Comment: You can also throw an `InvalidPluginExecutionException` to "debug" your code, rude but works. First thing I will check the `collection.Entities.Count` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. SetState event is not called, so i change the event to "setentitystate" and use the InvalidPluginExecutionException, as you say and i find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try registering your plugin also for the `SetStateDynamicEntity` message, in addition to doing the same for `SetState`. From my experience, entities need to be registered for both in order to work, although I'm not 100% clear on whether it's necessary, I know for a fact that it works. Several searches did not give me a definitive answer. Check out this popular CRM blog with the same suggestion. http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/plug-in-for-setstate-and-setstatedynamicentity-messages/

I know with entities that I've worked with, failing to register for SetStateDynamic will cause the plugin not to trigger.